# mogenerator doesn't generate any entities even though datamodel contains entities. Reports "No entities found in model. No files will be generated."

Tags: ios, core-data, mogenerator

I'm trying to get mogenerator (1.26 latest) to generate some boiler plate classes from a core data model (xcdatamodel) and it reports:

```
No entities found in model. No files will be generated.
(model description: (<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x10012e410>) isEditable 1, entities {
}, fetch request templates {
})
```

Even though the contents of the xcdatamodel clearly exist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model name="" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="" type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="1487" systemVersion="11E53" minimumToolsVersion="Xcode 4.3" macOSVersion="Automatic" iOSVersion="Automatic">
    <entity name="Chair" representedClassName="Chair" syncable="YES">
        <attribute name="name" attributeType="String" maxValueString="50" syncable="YES"/>
    </entity>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Xcode 4.4.1 and mogenerator 1.26

Answer (score 10):

This is a quote from http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/

> When you create entities in your data model, be sure to populate the
>   “Class” field with the same name as the entity.

So what you have to do is:

- Open your data model
- Select your entity
- In the right panel, select the Data Model Inspector (3rd one)
- Edit the "Class" field with the same name as the "Name" field

Comment: Nice one this just helped me end about 3 hours of frustration